# OneToMany - org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

Tags: java, hibernate-4.x, hibernate-tools, openxava

I'm trying to generate the DB schema from my domain classes using the hibernate-tools.jar bundled in OpenXava.

Unfortunately, two classes with a *OneToMany* association are causing me troubles.

This is the first one:

```
@Entity
public class Deceased extends ObjectWithId {

    //stuff

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "deceased", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    public Set<DeceasedTransferDossier> getDeceasedTransferDossier() {
        return deceasedTransferDossier;
    }

    public void setDeceasedTransferDossier(
            Set<DeceasedTransferDossier> transferDossiers) {
        this.deceasedTransferDossier = transferDossiers;
    }

    //other stuff
}
```

This is the other one:

```
@Entity
public class DeceasedTransferDossier extends DeceasedDossier {

    //stuff

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "deceased_fk")
    @Override
    public Deceased getDeceased() {
        return deceased;
    }

    @Override
    public void setDeceased(Deceased deceased) {
        this.deceased = deceased;
    }

    //other stuff
}
```

This is the exception that gets raised:

```
[hibernatetool] An exception occurred while running exporter #2:hbm2ddl (Generates database schema)
[hibernatetool] To get the full stack trace run ant with -verbose
[hibernatetool] org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.infoone.siglo.entity.DeceasedTransferDossier.deceased in com.infoone.siglo.entity.Deceased.deceasedTransferDossier
      [ant] Exiting C:\Users\AlejandroEduardo\Documents\workspace-sts-3.1.0.RELEASE-2\OpenXava\build.xml.

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\AlejandroEduardo\Documents\workspace-sts-3.1.0.RELEASE-2\SigloXava\build.xml:46: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\AlejandroEduardo\Documents\workspace-sts-3.1.0.RELEASE-2\OpenXava\build.xml:1016: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.infoone.siglo.entity.DeceasedTransferDossier.deceased in com.infoone.siglo.entity.Deceased.deceasedTransferDossier
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:551)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:444)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)
Caused by: C:\Users\AlejandroEduardo\Documents\workspace-sts-3.1.0.RELEASE-2\OpenXava\build.xml:1016: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.infoone.siglo.entity.DeceasedTransferDossier.deceased in com.infoone.siglo.entity.Deceased.deceasedTransferDossier
    at org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask.reportException(HibernateToolTask.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask.execute(HibernateToolTask.java:189)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseSingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseSingleCheckExecutor.java:30)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.infoone.siglo.entity.DeceasedTransferDossier.deceased in com.infoone.siglo.entity.Deceased.deceasedTransferDossier
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:666)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:626)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1586)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1359)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1300)
    at org.hibernate.tool.ant.ConfigurationTask.getConfiguration(ConfigurationTask.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask.getConfiguration(HibernateToolTask.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.tool.ant.Hbm2DDLExporterTask.createExporter(Hbm2DDLExporterTask.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.ant.ExporterTask.execute(ExporterTask.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask.execute(HibernateToolTask.java:186)
    ... 29 more
```

Let me point out some possible sources of harm:

1. The class *DeceasedTransferDossier* extends *DeceasedDossier*, that already has a non-abstract *getDeceased()* accessor;
2. All the entities have a common parent class, named *Identifiable*:

   ```
   @MappedSuperclass
   public class Identifiable {

       private String id;

       public void setId(String id) {
           this.id = id;
       }
       @Id @GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid") @Hidden 
       @GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
       @Column(length=32)
       public String getId() {
           return id;
       }
   }
   ```

Let me point out that such a structure already works in a Spring-data + Hibernate container, where the DB schema gets successfully created (Spring-data 3.1.2 + Hibernate 4.1.6)
OpenXava bundles an older version of Hibernate and Hibernate Tools, therefore I tried to tweak it manually, updating it to:

- Hibernate Tools 4.0.0.CR1 (the most recent version I could find at Maven Repository);
- Hibernate  4.0.0.Final (the version Hibernate Tools 4.0.0.CR1 depends on);
- and updating all the necessary dependeces on cascade.

I hoped such update could solve my problem but, unfortunately, the org.hibernate.AnnotationException remained the same.

Comment: try with `targetEntity`

Comment: `targetEntity` is supposed to work only with wrapper classes, like Integer, Long and similar stuff, isn't it? Furthermore, as the exception witnesses, the targetEntity class is identified correctly. The problem is that that peculiar field/property inside the targetEntity class cannot be seen.

Comment: btw you have a method `getDeceased` in parent class that return another decesaed? you are breaking liskov substitution principle

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies with the fact that you are extending DeceasedDossier and essentially changing (or defining?) the relationship between the descedent class (DeceasedTransferDossier) and Deceased.

We do not know what the ancestor (DeceasedDossier) looks like, but it could be a few things. Either you are not annotating this class and so you are running into issues when the persistence provider tries to "figure out" what deceased means to DeceasedTransferDossier. Or, you are annotating it incorrectly. I guess there could also be another issue, but again we would need to see DeceasedDossier.

So, solution without really knowing what is going on with DeceasedDossier:

1. If you are not annotating the DecreasedDossier class, then just tell the provider you are using PROPERTY access for deceased, on DeceasedTransferDossier.

   ```
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "deceased_fk")
   @Override
   @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
   public Deceased getDeceased() {
       return deceased;
   }
   ```
2. If you ARE annotating DeceasedDossier, then we need to see the problem to figure it out. But, I bet you by just adding the @Access annotation on DeceasedTransferDossier's deceased getter, you will expose the root problem in this case (when the provider tries to "figure out" what is going on with DeceasedDossier.

Finally, I have to say that this seems like an odd relationship here. I imagine DeceasedDossier has Deceased state (an instance variable) since you mention the "non-abstract getter", but you are also defining such a relationship in the descendent. Since your question isn't about this, I won't "critique", but maybe review why you have split it up as such.